# How to set optimal width for labels column in jqgrid edit and view forms

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid edit and view forms row labels (they are same as column captions ) are set at runtime.
Sometimes they are narrow and sometimes wide.

For narrow labels column width in too big. There is too much empty place between label text and value field.

It looks like `labelswidth: '30%'` value is hard coded.

How to adjust edit and view form labels columns width automatically so that if all labels are narrow, column width is smaller ?

Answer (score 0):

The first which I would try to do is to use the values in pixel instead of percents:

```
labelswidth: 80, width: 600
```

Comment: Thank you. label texts can changed by user at runtime. So different forms need different labelswidth values. How to calculate labelswidth value automatically ? How to force label text to wrap to next line if it is wider that label column width ? Currently for checkbox columns label text and checkbox will overlap which is very ugly. Can jqgrid column header wrapping style used for this ?

Comment: labelswidth propery is not specified in applicaton. For edit window labels column width is correct: column width is set automatically according to largest label width. How to force same behaviour for view window ?